# After an ETA calculation, date and time not showing correctly. (Whole PHP code)

Tags: php, date, time

Please see the comments within the php.

Truck fleet ETA calculator

Distances in Kilometers : city a to city b

```
$dist_city_a_city_b = 475;
```

Loading/Preparation time

```
$turnaround = 45;
```

Departure time

```
$departtime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo "Distance: $dist_city_a_city_b Kilometers<br>";

$distM = $dist_city_a_city_b*1000;
echo "Distance: $distM in meters<br>";
```

Speed constant in Kilometers per Hour

```
$speed = 80/3.6;
echo "Speed: $speed converted to meters/second<br>";

$eta_1 = $distM/$speed;

echo "Distance / Speed: $eta_1<br>";

$eta = $eta_1/60;

echo "All in minutes = $eta<br>";

$arivaltime = $eta + $turnaround;  

echo "Arriveal in minutes including turnaround: $arivaltime<br>";

echo "Depart Time: ".$departtime."<br>";
```

Here below is the problem not showing date properly after calculation 
Need the code below to show the ETA in proper format added the calculated travel time to the departure time, which is 356.25 minutes, meaning if moved at 12:00 noon, then it should show same day date and almost 18:00 hrs, and if 23:00 then it should move to next day date and hour which would be 05:00

```
echo "Arrival Time: " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($arivaltime, strtotime($departtime))) . " (ETA)<br>";
```

The rest of the code will be the postings to mysql table

Output:

```
Distance: 475 Kilometers

Distance: 475000 in meters

Speed: 22.222222222222 converted to meters/second

Distance / Speed: 21375

All in minutes = 356.25

Arriveal in minutes including turnaround: 401.25

Depart Time: 2015-05-21 23:53:03

Arrival Time: 1970-01-01 04:00:00 (ETA)
```

Thank you all

SamimiIT

Comment: So what is it showing instead of the proper date?

Comment: Edited! now showing the output. The last line ETA gets reported wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take departure time, add travel time in seconds, and then format it:

```
echo "Arrival Time: " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($departtime) + $arivaltime * 60) . " (ETA)<br>";
```

I would rename many variables to make more sense out of it.

```
 $eta_1 -> $travel_seconds
 $arivaltime -> $travel_minutes
```

Comment: Thank you mike for the variables rename tip as well. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially trying to get a date from a single number. Try this:

```
$arrival = strtotime($departtime) + ($arivaltime * 60);
echo "Arrival Time: " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $arrival) . " (ETA)<br>";
```